# Add control to storyboard after selecting text from picker view

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add controls i.e. Textfield, label, Button to a view at runtime. we need to select a control displayed in picker view and add the corresponding control will be displayed on screen.

Comment: have you done anything ??

Comment: have you write some code for it ? paste your code in question

Comment: add some sample code